# Angular 2 Testing: What's the correct way for async testing?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular, karma-jasmine

I have the following test in an angular 2 project with karma and jasmine:

```
let a: any;

beforeEach(() => {
    a = {};

    setTimeout(() => {
        a.test();
    }, 1000);
});

it('should work with async and promise', async(() => {

   return new Promise((resolve) => {
       a.test = () => {
           console.log('erster test');
           assertThat(true, is(false));
           resolve();
       };
   });
}));

it('should work with async and done', async((done) => {

    a.test = () => {
        console.log('zweiter test');
        assertThat(true, is(false));
        done();
    };
}));

it('should work with done', (done) => {

    a.test = () => {
        console.log('dritter test');
        assertThat(true, is(false));
        done();
    };
});
```

The only case that works (means it fails) is the last one with just a "done" callback. With the second one I'm not sure but shouldn't the first one be the correct way to test async in angular 2? I thought with "async" you place a zone around your function and it's waiting for the returned promise? I tried to make sense of the async implementation but I'm not getting it: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/testing/async.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zone gets created [*inside* the `async` method](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/core/testing/async.ts#L41). So your `setTimeout` (in the `beforeEach`) is not inside that zone. If you move the `setTimeout` to *inside* the `async` callback, then it is in the zone, and the tests should work as expected (meaning wait for the asynchronous tasks to complete).

```
it('should work with async and promise', async(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    a.test();
  }, 1000);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    a.test = () => {
      console.log('erster test');
      expect(true).toBe(false);
      resolve();
    };
  });
}));

it('should work with async and done', async((done: Function) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    a.test();
  }, 1000);
  a.test = () => {
    console.log('zweiter test');
    expect(true).toBe(false);
    done();
  };
}));
```

Comment: thank you, maybe my examples wasn't that good. "a" is in fact the reference to a video tag and "test()" is the "onplay" function of it. So I guess I can't move the call of onplay in the zone because it's fired by the video itself right? Do I have to take "done" here or is there a solution with async/zones?

Comment: I don't know. I don't really have any experience testing video, and I'm not completely sure what you mean. If you post a real example, maybe I can play with it :-)

Comment: sorry I tried to create a plunker but couldn't get it to run. But your hint the caller also needs to be in the zone helped me understand it. At the end I just used done only and it works.